# Springboot: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: spring, http-status-code-415

These are my headers: [Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy06a.png)

This error cropped up out of nowhere. I've been sending POST requests to my application without error for a while now. My Post method reads:

Controller:

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/generateCredential", consumes="multipart/form-data")
 @ApiOperation(value = "User can register using this Api", response = RegisterForPluginResponse.class)
 public ResponseEntity<Object> generateCredential(@Valid @RequestBody RegisterForPluginRequest registerForPlugin) {
  ...
 }
```

dto:

```
 public RegisterForPluginRequest() {
        super();
    }
 public RegisterForPluginRequest(@Email @NotEmpty String clientName, @NotEmpty int packageId, String phone, String email) {
        super();
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.packageId = packageId;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

What could cause a 415 error where previously there was none? I did recently make changes to make changes to my application's SQL table by adding 2 columns, I wonder if this could be the source of my problem?

Comment: The line you posted doesn't look like having any issue. you need to add more information like controller method.

Comment: @code_mechanic I've added details to the controller and the dto it utilizes

Comment: Try removing the `@RequestBody` from your parameter, it is expecting JSON as request, hence giving 415.

Comment: @code_mechanic that fixed it, I love you

Comment: love you too, glad it helped.